# Import file.xml to postgresql 9.3,copy all data including header

Tags: xml, postgresql

how to import data *.xml(taken from sql server)

[image: some of the xml file]

To

PostgreSQL 9.3..Already create table with same column XML.now problem to maping data.any help.

thanks you

Comment: Well, what did you already try? Did you research XML conversions / data loading at all? Take a look at ETL tools like Talend Studio, CloverETL, and Pentaho Kettle, as well as the large number of utility scripts out there. How exactly was the XML document extracted/created in the first place - and can you extract it in a more useful form than this, or connect directly to the MS SQL server to query it, rather than having to use an XML dump?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to import an XML document into PostgreSQL, simply:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(mydata xml);

INSERT INTO mytable(mydata) VALUES ('<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ROOT>
  <xsd:schema ....>')
```

If you instead want to take an XML document and extract its contents into a set of related tables, there's no automagic way to do that. Look at Talend Studio, Pentaho Kettle, CloverETL, and the large variety of XML import utility scripts and tools out there. No matter how you do it, you'll have to define some kind of schema mapping from your XML document to the PostgreSQL schema you wish to load the document contents into.

Comment: thank you sir.already try a few tool such as ETL.your suggested tools will try in shortly.later i will update to you